# Issues with creating two checkboxes in a GUI

Tags: python-3.x, checkbox, tkinter

I am doing a project for school, but I am stuck at the point of the creation of multiple checkboxes. I copy/pasted some code and messed around with it, trying to get two checkboxes, but I was unable to do so. The checkboxes use the same variable to tick/untick (I know this). I am unable to find a way to get a second variable to allow the second checkbox to be ticked or unticked depending on whether the first is unticked or ticked.

```python
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Payroll")
root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
class App:
    def __init__(self,master):
        root.minsize(width=500, height=500)
        root.maxsize(width=500, height=500)
        self.var = IntVar()
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.grid()
        f2 = Frame(master,width=200,height=100)
        f2.grid(row=0,column=1)
        btnSalary = Checkbutton(frame,text='Salary',variable=self.var,command=self.fx)
        btnWage = Checkbutton(frame,text='Wage',variable=self.var,command= self.fx)
        btnSalary.grid(row=0,column=0)
        btnWage.grid(row=2,column=0)
        msg1="Wage"
        self.v= Message(f2,text=msg1)
        msg2="Salary"
        self.v= Message(f2,text=msg2)
    def fx(self):
        if self.var.get():
            self.v.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky=N)
        else:
            self.v.grid_remove()
app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand the Question. What should happen if you use the checkboxes. Can you please provide a usecase

Comment: Ok, I think i got it. If I understand your Questions correctly you properly need checkbutton. See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm

Comment: @VRage: if the choice is exclusive (_either_ Salary _or_ Wage), a Checkbutton is the wrong choice.

Answer (score 0):

Checkbuttons and Radiobuttons have very specific use cases:

- You would use one or more **Checkbuttons** when the user can check none, any, or all of the options. A checkbutton always has two values, an `onvalue` and an `offvalue` (typically `True` and `False`, answering the question "is it checked").
- You would use one or more **Radiobuttons** when the user can pick exactly one choice from a set of choices.

If your case it looks like you're wanting the user to choose *either* Salary *or* Wage. If that is true, you need to use Radiobuttons, not Checkbuttons. When you use Radiobuttons, all of the choices that act as one must use the same `textvariable`. This is how Tkinter knows they work as a set. Also, you must give each Radiobutton a distinct value, so that when you get the value you will know which one is selected.

In your case, the widgets might look something like this:

```
btnSalary = Radiobutton(..., variable=self.var,value="salary", ...)
btnWage = Radiobutton(...,variable=self.var, value="wage", ...)
```